# Cannot generate opcode A1 for mov eax, [STATIC_ADDRESS]

Tags: visual-c++, inline-assembly, mov

This is the opcode that I want to recreate with the inline assembler :

```
004863AF - A1 2C66C700           - mov eax,[00C7662C]
```

So far I've tried the following :

```
void __declspec(naked) SelectTarget(int MobID)
{
    __asm
    {
        mov eax, dword ptr [0x00C7662C]
        mov eax, [0x00C7662C]
        mov eax, 0x00C7662C
        mov eax, 00C7662Ch
        //...
    }
}
```

And this is the result :

```
    XyPW.SelectTarget - B8 2C66C700           - mov eax,00C7662C
    XyPW.SelectTarget+5- B8 2C66C700           - mov eax,00C7662C
    XyPW.SelectTarget+A- B8 2C66C700           - mov eax,00C7662C
    XyPW.SelectTarget+F- B8 2C66C700           - mov eax,00C7662C
```

While this could be easily fixed by following it with `mov eax, [eax]`, I would like to :

1. Understand why is a `B8 mov` being generate
2. Learn how to properly generate a `A1 mov`

Comment: `B8` is used to move immediate values, `A1` is used to move values at memory offsets. Perhaps you meant `8B`which are generated for memory offsets using ModRM + SIB?

Comment: `A1`[Loading value at offset] is what I want to do. The problem is that I can't generate `A1` through inline assembler. Everything I tried became a `B8`.

Comment: it's quite possible that visual c++ doesn't generate that instruction, since it is a specialized `mov` for `rAX`, and only produces `8B` ones.

Comment: I think didierc is correct. However If you really wanted that instruction on VC++ you may have to use `_emit` to produce each byte. Putting this in your `_asm` block may work if VC++ won't generate it for you: `_emit 0xA1; _emit 0x2C; _emit 0x66; _emit 0xC7, _emit 0x00`
`

Comment: If your intent is to simply try and get VC++ to do indirect addressing (but don't care specifically about the generated opcode) then this should work `mov eax, ds:[0x00C7662C]`. It appears that VC++ inline assembler wants you to specify the segment register. This will however produce the instruction this way: `3E A1 2C 66 C7 00` which ultimately translates to `mov eax,dword ptr ds:[00C7662Ch]` Of course you should use whatever segment is applicable for your situation. I just assumed `ds`